# How to create Home.aspx page in SharePoint Team Site using CSOM in C#?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-online, csom

Is there any way to create the homepage Home.aspx in Sharepoint under the template Team Site using CSOM in C# ?

Answer (score 1):

The following code snippet for your reference.

```
string siteUrl = "https://*****.sharepoint.com/sites/team";
string userName = "admin@****.onmicrosoft.com";
string password = "***";

OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager authMgr = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();

#region O365
using (var ctx = authMgr.GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant(siteUrl, userName, password))
{
    Web web = ctx.Web;
    ctx.Load(web.Lists);
    ctx.Load(web, w => w.SupportedUILanguageIds);
    ctx.Load(web);

    ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
    //Create the Page
    var homePage = ctx.Web.AddClientSidePage("HomePage.aspx", true);
    homePage.AddSection(CanvasSectionTemplate.ThreeColumn, 5);  
    homePage.Save();
}
```

More information is here: [How To Create A Modern Pages Programmatically In SharePoint Office 365 Using Patterns And Practice (OfficeDevPNP)](https://www.sharepointpals.com/post/how-to-create-a-modern-pages-programmatically-in-sharepoint-office-365-using-patterns-and-practice-officedevpnp/)

We can also use PnP PowerShell below to achieve it.

```
$siteUrl="https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/team";
$cred = Get-Credential
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -Credential $cred
Add-PnPClientSidePage  -Name "HomePage"
Set-PnPHomePage -RootFolderRelativeUrl SitePages/HomePage.aspx
```

Comment: Ya that's cool but I need to create the page using CSOM and not using OfficeDevPnP

Comment: You can refer to the source code of the OfficeDevPnP.Core here: https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/tree/master/Core/OfficeDevPnP.Core

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach:

```
OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager authMgr = new OfficeDevPnP.Core.AuthenticationManager();

             string siteUrl = "https://******.sharepoint.com/sites/CommunitySite";
             string userName = "userh@******.onmicrosoft.com";
             string password = "******";

             using (var ctx = authMgr.GetSharePointOnlineAuthenticatedContextTenant(siteUrl, userName, password))
             {
                 Web web = ctx.Web;
                 ctx.Load(web);
                 ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();

                 List sitePagesList = web.Lists.GetByTitle("Site Pages");

                 ctx.Load(sitePagesList);
                 ctx.Load(sitePagesList.RootFolder);
                 ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();

                 var pageTitle = "home.aspx";
                 sitePagesList.RootFolder.Files.AddTemplateFile(sitePagesList.RootFolder.ServerRelativeUrl + "/" + pageTitle, TemplateFileType.StandardPage);

                 ctx.ExecuteQueryRetry();
             }
         }
```

Switch between modern and classic design:

```
#Get the Web Scoped Feature

 $web = $context.Web
 # Feature Title : EnableDefaultListLibrarExperience, Scope : Web
 $featureguid = new-object System.Guid "52E14B6F-B1BB-4969-B89B-C4FAA56745EF" 

 #To Enable/Disable the Modern UI, comment and uncomment the below two lines, either to Add or Remove
 #$web.Features.Add($featureguid, $true, [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.FeatureDefinitionScope]::None)
 $web.Features.Remove($featureguid, $true)        

 $context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Comment: I need to create only the home.aspx page and not the site

Comment: you can use the o365 CLI to create the site, see above

Comment: Actually, I don't need to create the site. I just need to create a page (modern page) using CSOM